# OpenVPN bridging

Tags: linux, openvpn

I was wondering, if I am setting up an Linux OpenVPN server using ethernet bridging rather than a routed tunnel. Do I still need to push a route to the client that is connecting to me?

I am setting OpenVPN to use DHCP proxy instead of giving it a pre defined pool.

What do I need to still configure, other than the SSL params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here are [my OpenVPN configuration notes](http://www.hollenback.net/index.php/OpenVpnSetup) as a general starting point.

And here are the [OpenVPN docs about bridging](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html).

The short answer is that if you set up a bridged openvpn config *and* you use a split tunnel, the clients will be directly connected *only* to the server's network via the vpn.  If you want the clients to be able to connect to other networks beyond that on the server side, you need to push one or more routes to them via the vpn.

If you don't use a split tunnel (all traffic goes through the vpn, via the [redirect-gateway](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) setting), then you can use the dhcp server config to push a default gateway to the hosts, and they can use that (over the vpn) to get to other networks, or out to the internet.  You also need to use an iptables nat config as detailed in the docs.

Comment: Oh I see, if all traffic is going over the tunnel then no need for routes. But if I am using a split I have to route the traffic. Makes sense if I got it right.

Comment: Yup you got it.